# Can I import certain tables from a remote database over SSH into the main database for a Wordpress install?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, ssh, remote-access

I would like to be able to sync certain tables from a remotely hosted database into a Wordpress database, these tables are not containing any related Wordpress content. These tables contain simple warranty lookup info that returns a simple yes/no if a specific serial number of a product is past the warranty date. I have SSH and privileges set up for this and my IP is whitelisted.

On the management side, the user enters this data into an internal system that pushes the information to their server hosting the database.

My goal is not to disrupt the system they are using and simply use a form on the site to access the lookup feature with the imported data from the external database. I hope this makes sense.

I appreciate any help or guidance in this.

Comment: This is all a bit fuzzy. You will have to decide what you actually want to do: import or sync or access. If you want to import, then dump whatever data you need on the remote side, `scp` it to the local system and import it. If you want to sync, then read about "mysql replication". Or you decide to directly access the remote data on that mysql server, such access can easily be tunneled by means of ssh.

Comment: how might I use SSH tunneling on a live wp site to another live site? Is there a useful guide? I am struggling with the search results I am finding.

Comment: You want to learn how to setup a ssh tunnel. That is independent of what that tunnel is used for. You set it up such that it relays the remote mysql port to some port on your local system. Then you can make a normal connection to that local port and you will be able to login to that remote mysql server, even if a direct connection to that remote port is not possible due to network topology or a firewall.

Comment: I would give your WP install as little access to your other server as possible as it is a great attack vector.  Personally I would allow your remote server to connect to your WP Database and then set up a php script on the remote server to do what ever replication you need.

Comment: So what I've decided to do is use the ssh tunneling approach. Wasn't that bad! I appreciate the insight :)